# Seperation of trigger with helper class

Tags: trigger

I got the below code written in a trigger and I need to separate it out to a helper class as a method and call that method in the trigger.

```
trigger setCountry on Account(after update){  
    List<BusinessHours> BusinessHoursId = new List<BusinessHours >();
        BusinessHoursId.add([Select Id from BusinessHours where Name ='austria']);
        BusinessHoursId.add([Select Id from BusinessHours where Name ='England']);
        BusinessHoursId.add([Select Id from BusinessHours where Name ='Africa']);
        BusinessHoursId.add([Select Id from BusinessHours where Name ='Canda']);
        BusinessHoursId.add([Select Id from BusinessHours where Name ='Australia']);
    list<Case> listCase= new list<Case>();
    try{
        for(Account ac : trigger.new){ 
            if(ac.Country_Name___c!=trigger.oldMap.get(ac.id).Country__c)
            {
                listCase=[Select BusinessHoursId from case where accountid=:ac.id];
                for(Case c:listCase){
                    if(acc.Country_Name__c =='England')
                    {
                        c.BusinessHoursId = BusinessHoursId[1].id;
                    } 
                    else if(ac.Country_Name__c =='austria')
                    {
                         c.BusinessHoursId = BusinessHoursId[0].id;
                    }
                    else if(ac.Country_Name__c =='canda')
                    {
                        c.BusinessHoursId =BusinessHoursId[3].id;
                    }
                    else if(ac.Country_Name__c =='Australia')
                    {
                        c.BusinessHoursId =BusinessHoursId[4].id;
                    }
                    else if(ac.Country_Name__c =='LAN')
                    {
                        c.BusinessHoursId =BusinessHoursId[5].id;
                    }                       
                 }
            update listCase;                             
            }
        }
      }
        catch(Exception e){
            system.debug ('error: ' + e.getMessage() );
    }   
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can move the code to a helper class. Basically, you just move the entire piece of code into a static method of another class and pass in your trigger context variables to that method. Please note that your trigger code does not follow the best practice of [bulkification](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code). It is highly recommeded that you fix that as well.

**Trigger**

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account(after update){  

      if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate)
      {
        AccountTrigger.handleAfterUpdate(Trigger.New,Trigger.OldMap);
      }

 }
```

**Helper Class**

```
public class AccountTriggerHelper {

 public static void handleAfterUpdate(List<Account> accountSoLst, Map<Id,Account> oldMap) {

  List<BusinessHours> BusinessHoursId = new List<BusinessHours >();
        BusinessHoursId.add([Select Id from BusinessHours where Name ='austria']);
        BusinessHoursId.add([Select Id from BusinessHours where Name ='England']);
        BusinessHoursId.add([Select Id from BusinessHours where Name ='Africa']);
        BusinessHoursId.add([Select Id from BusinessHours where Name ='Canda']);
        BusinessHoursId.add([Select Id from BusinessHours where Name ='Australia']);
    list<Case> listCase= new list<Case>();

    try 
    {
      for(Account ac : accountSoLst) 
      {
         if(ac.Country_Name___c!=oldMap.get(ac.id).Country__c)
            {
                listCase=[Select BusinessHoursId from case where accountid=:ac.id];
                for(Case c:listCase){
                    if(acc.Country_Name__c =='England')
                    {
                        c.BusinessHoursId = BusinessHoursId[1].id;
                    } 
                    else if(ac.Country_Name__c =='austria')
                    {
                         c.BusinessHoursId = BusinessHoursId[0].id;
                    }
                    else if(ac.Country_Name__c =='canda')
                    {
                        c.BusinessHoursId =BusinessHoursId[3].id;
                    }
                    else if(ac.Country_Name__c =='Australia')
                    {
                        c.BusinessHoursId =BusinessHoursId[4].id;
                    }
                    else if(ac.Country_Name__c =='LAN')
                    {
                        c.BusinessHoursId =BusinessHoursId[5].id;
                    }                       
                 }
            update listCase;                             
           }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
            system.debug ('error: ' + e.getMessage() );
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: can anyone give me idea how to write test class for above trigger?